# Scala type checking compilation error

Tags: scala, compilation, compiler-errors, functional-programming

I have the following functions

```
  def map[A,B](l: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B]

  def concat[A](l: List[List[A]]): List[A]
```

I wanted to implement this one

```
  def flatMap[A,B](l: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B]
```

Now, I know that a correct solution is (so this is not the question)

```
  def flatMap[A,B](l: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = 
    concat(map(l)(f))
```

But when I was trying to resolve it, I first tried with (I forgot to concat)

```
  def flatMap[A,B](l: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = 
    map(l)(f)

// compilation output
[error]  found   : A => fpinscala.datastructures.List[B]
[error]  required: A => B
[error]     map(l)(f)
```

I cannot understand that error, because looks like the evaluation of the `map(l)(f)` is wrong, but it is not, it is the returned value of the flatMap function what is wrong.

In fact, if a decompose the same implementation in two lines of code, we can see that the Scala compiler complains about another different error - actually is the error that I expected also in the previous code.

```
  def flatMap[A,B](l: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = {
    var result = map(l)(f)
    result
  }

// compilation output
[error]  found   : fpinscala.datastructures.List[fpinscala.datastructures.List[B]]
[error]  required: fpinscala.datastructures.List[B]
[error]     result
```

Could anyone explain me why the compilation of the first try of code is given a different kind of error that the second one?

Comment: I agree but this does not explain why Scala compiler complains about it in the first code but not in the second. The only difference is that en the second I am storing the result in a variable but the map function call is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to know how Scala check types. It is using an [Unification algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29). In simple words it means that it follows a top/down approach.

Recall that `map` is of type `List[U] => (U => V) => List[V]` (whatever type `U` and `V` are). In the first wrong code, you wrote that your function returns a `List[B]`. Therefore you tell Scala that `map(l)(f)` must be of type `List[B]`. Now you propagate the constains in a top/down way. For `map(l)(f)` to be of type `List[B]`, you need to have `l` of type `List[A]` (whatever `A` is) and `f` of type `A => B`. Thus the compiler is complaining because you gave `f` of type `A => list[B]`.

If the second wrong code, you already correctly computed `result` of type `List[List[B]]`. However, in the second line you try to return `result` but your function is declared to return a `list[B]`. Hence the error message.

Comment: I understand what you said, but why the error of the first code is not applicable to the second one? I still cannot see the difference between `map(l)(f)` and `var result = map(l)(f)`.

Comment: Because you didn't specify any type for `result` at this stage. So it is perfectly ok to define it that way an the type is `List[List[B]]`. The problem come when you try to return it. If you write `var result : List[B] = map(l)(f)` then you should get the same error.

Comment: It is totally clear the error of the second code and that's not the point. The question is why the evaluation of the first map is wrong for the compiler and the second it is not. In an imperative language, the expected error will be the same (no matters if you store the result in several variables before to return it), in that case the error that is raising the second code.

Comment: Rafa: That's not true. You will have the same kind of behaviour in C++ if you declare result with type `auto`.

Comment: @Rafa : the expected error will be the same for the **same code**, and your examples are **not**. Try running it with a debugger and check the type signatures along the way (or just use an IDE that shows you the inferred types).

Comment: I think I finally understood it. So in the first code, because Scala knows that the map itself is the returning value of the flatMap function, it happens what @hivert explained in its second paragraph. In the second one, because Scala knows that the map is not the returning value, it does not assume that the map output type must to be List[B] like in the first code does. WoW, it is a big shift of thinking coming from OOP. Thanks a lot to both. I believe this thread is going to be very useful for those like me who just started to learn functional programming.

Comment: @Rafa: close - the type signature of `map(l)(f)` is the same `List[List[B]]`, but, because you don't specify the type of `result`, Scala has to [infer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) it - it choses, sensibly, `List[List[B]]`, because that's the type of the right-hand side of the `=` operation. Only after you try to use `result` as the returned value, the error occurs. If you would explicitly write `var result: List[B] = map(l)(f)`, the error would appear on that very line. This has little to do with "OOP" vs "functional", it's about the more powerful type inference in Scala.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato: now all makes sense for me. Very explanatory your last comment. Thanks!

Comment: I'm quite happy with that one, given that It's the first time I read some Scala code ;-). I know however OCaml very well and it is quite close to scala...